# looping with ImageDraw.Draw(image) in Python results in overlaid text

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

When executing the following code the first output file works perfectly but the second one draws the text from both the first and second items in the list. The text continues to accumulate for each iteration. However, the filenames are fine and don`t accumulate.

```
def write_text_to_image(names_list):
    from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
    image = Image.open("t.bmp")
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image) 
    font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 132)

    for name in names_list:
        draw.text((150, 905), name, font = font, fill = (0, 0, 0))
        image.save(name + ".bmp")
```

Answer (score 2):

I answered the question myself Fabio`s idea helped. I had to move the image assignment within the for loop.

```
def write_text_to_image(names_list):
    from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
    font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 132)

    for name in names_list:
        image = Image.open("t.bmp")
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image) 
        draw.text((150, 905), name, font = font, fill = (0, 0, 0))
        image.save(name + ".bmp")
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try but looking at your code I think object `draw` must be recreated on each interation:

```
for name in names_list:
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    ...
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I moved the line of code into the loop and it still doing the same thing.